# Create new object structure from related data with matching keys

Tags: typescript

Im attempting to group related data `IOrderData` together by the `productId`, and `brandId`, to form a new array of objects `IOrderTypeData` with the delivery type being the only difference between the objects. The brand id / product id can be combined with any set, so the groupings need to be unique per product id / brand id, meaning each one should have its own record.

Assumming the following interfaces and data

```js
interface IOrderData {
  brandId: number
  productIds: number[] // api sends as array, but only ever include one id
  deliveryType: string //air, ground, ship, train
  moreData: string
  moreMoreData: number
}

interface IProduct {
  productId: number
  desc: string
}

interface IOrderTypeData {
  brandId: number
  product: IProduct
  deliveryTypes: IOrderData[]
}

const products = [
  {
    productId: 100,
    desc: "some desc"
  },
  {
    productId: 200,
    desc: "some desc"
  }
]

const orderData = [
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [100],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [100],
      deliveryType: "Air",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [200],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [200],
      deliveryType: "Air",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [100],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [100],
      deliveryType: "Air",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [200],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [200],
      deliveryType: "Air",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  }
];
```

I have struggled for hours using a combination of `reduce` and looping to achieve the desired result. Ive tried grouping the data on each id and filtering down but my solution causes an infinite loop in the browser.

The first step I've tried doing is filtering the records down to the brand id in a loop.

**Desired Result**

```
const groupedData = [
  {
    brandId: 1,
    product: {
      productId: 100,
      desc: "some desc"
    },
    deliveryTypes: [
      {
        brandId: 1,
        productIds: [100],
        deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      },
      {
        brandId: 1,
        productIds: [100],
        deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    brandId: 1,
    product: {
      productId: 200,
      desc: "some desc"
    },
    deliveryTypes: [
      {
        brandId: 1,
        productIds: [200],
        deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      },
      {
        brandId: 1,
        productIds: [200],
        deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    brandId: 2,
    product: {
      productId: 100,
      desc: "some desc"
    },
    deliveryTypes: [
      {
        brandId: 2,
        productIds: [100],
        deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      },
      {
        brandId: 2,
        productIds: [100],
        deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    brandId: 2,
    product: {
      productId: 200,
      desc: "some desc"
    },
    deliveryTypes: [
      {
        brandId: 2,
        productIds: [200],
        deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      },
      {
        brandId: 2,
        productIds: [200],
        deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What _specifically_ have you tried, and what's the problem with it? Give a [mre].

Comment: I posted this as I was leaving house to drop kid off. Realized I forgot will be back shortly and will post sorry.

Comment: `desc: "some desc"`: where did that come from?

Comment: `deliveryTypeOne` ... `deliveryTypeTwo`: that's a bad idea. Use arrays. You don't want to continue like that until `deliveryTypeOneHundredAndTwentyNine`.

Comment: That’s a good point. I was trying to adhere to legacy system I can’t rewrite but I can filter off the array and pass it in.

Comment: Sorry, I posted rushing out the door. Im fixing everything now and clarifying. Will post commend when finished.

Comment: question has been fixed. sorry guys

Comment: How is `moreMoreData` a `number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Array::reduce()` to accumulate breand/product items in the result and a map (for faster access to add additional delivery types).

Also there's no product description, so I've added a fake one.

```js
const result = orderData.reduce((r, item) => {
  
  const {brandId, productIds, ...delivery} = item;

  for(const id of productIds){

    const key = brandId + '.' + id;

    const found = r.map.get(key);
    if(found){
      found.deliveryTypes.push(item);
    }else{
      r.map.set(key, r.arr[r.arr.length] = {
        brandId, 
        product: {...products.find(({productId}) => productId === id)},
        deliveryTypes: [item], 
      });
    }

  }
  return r;

}, {arr: [], map: new Map}).arr;

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const orderData = [
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [22],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [22],
      deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Air",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
  },
]

const products = [
  {
    productId: 22,
    desc: "some desc"
  },
  {
    productId: 11,
    desc: "some desc"
  }
]

</script>
```

The OP complained about speed. I guess that's typescript compiled into some sh*t.
Here's benchmark of 600000 array items:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">
const chunk = [
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [22],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [22],
      deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data"
      
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
  },
  {
      brandId: 1,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Air",
        moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
        moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Ground",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
  },
  {
      brandId: 2,
      productIds: [11],
      deliveryType: "Air",
      moreData: "Some Preserved Data",
      moreMoreData: "Some Preserved Data",
  },
];

const orderData = [];

let count = 100000;
while(count--){
  orderData.push(...chunk);
}

const products = [
  {
    productId: 22,
    desc: "some desc"
  },
  {
    productId: 11,
    desc: "some desc"
  }
];

// @benchmark Alexander

orderData.reduce((r, item) => {
  
  const {brandId, productIds, ...delivery} = item;

  for(const id of productIds){

    const key = brandId + '.' + id;

    const found = r.map.get(key);
    if(found){
      found.deliveryTypes.push(item);
    }else{
      r.map.set(key, r.arr[r.arr.length] = {
        brandId, 
        product: {...products.find(({productId}) => productId === id)},
        deliveryTypes: [item], 
      });
    }

  }
  return r;

}, {arr: [], map: new Map}).arr;


</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ive updated my question with the correct data structruures

Comment: when running this I get .map.get is not a function

Comment: I got it working, realized I had a typo converting it to my actual values. The only issue is that this is super slow in react, taking over 10 seconds to process 200 rows.

Comment: @WebDevz added benchmark. 600000 rows made in 66 ms on my pc. I guess either typescript compiles sh*t or it's not my code

Comment: More than likely TS, I tested it early am in a pure js component and it was fine. thanks for the solution btw!